# TFS checkin and conflicts (i.e, checkin from not-latest checkout)

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm working on a .NET project versioned on TFS.

I'm using 2 different computer: pc#1 and pc#2.

The problem I'm getting is with "latest version" of the repository.

What happened:

- working on pc#1
- repository at version 10 (i.e., the latest changeset)
- need of rollback some files: checkout of specific version (version 8 checked out)
- edited a subset of files (e.g., f1, f2, f3)
- checkedin the modified version (changeset 11):
- - f1, f2 and f3 correctly checkedin
- - f4, f5 asked for conflict merge (these where files to version 8 not modified)
- - explicity selected to keep f4, f5 to "local version", i.e. as in changeset 8
- checkin is complete
- pc#1 is up to date, no pending changes now

Now the problem:

- working on pc#2
- checkout latest version (i.e., changeset 11)
- f1, f2 and f3 are just fine
- f4 and f5 are updated to version 10. This is an **undesired behaviour**: I would like to have them changeset 8

What did go wrong? I thought that, selecting "local version" for f4,f5, they would be set to use changeset 8 when checkouting changeset 11.

In this enviroment, if I force a recursive checkout on pc#1, f4,f5 are brought to changeset 10.

Am I able to set versions 8 of f4,f5 as the latest ones?